# How can I pass two keydown events at the same time with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way using jQuery or vanilla JS that I can pass down 2 keystrokes?

Example: When I press the space key as an event listener, both the enter and shift key should get pressed and passed down together. I managed for the code to run, but for one single key stroke. Can someone shine some light on this?

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == 13) {

        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
            console.log(ev.which);
        });

        var e = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
            'keyCode': 190,
            'which': 190
        });
        console.log(e);
        document.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you calling the actual function you're trying to trigger? This seems a bit like faxing an email.

Answer (score 1):

To add modifiers like `shift`, `ctrl`, or `alt` to a KeyPress event, you can pass those properties in the second constructor argument. See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent).

```js
// ex. Shift+Enter
var e = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
  key: "Enter",
  shiftKey: true,
});
```